# PHP: How to get value on basis of probability in array?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have below array

```
$a = [
 'c1' => '10',
 'c2' => '20',
 'c3' => '10.50',
 'c4' => '19.99'
 'c5' => '19',
 'c6' => '19',
 'c7' => '1.51',
];
```

> c1, c2, c3, c4,... is Value we need on basis of probability 10, 20, 10.50, 19.99,... .

Probability total is going to be 100%

So may be need to use `rand()` or `mt_rand()` function, so each time on basis of probability it gives random value from array.

Output can be c2 at 1st time, second time c4, third time may be c2 again

How to achieve this?

Comment: You want random value from $a array everytime?

Comment: Hi @PrabhjotSinghKainth can't be that case. Sometime it will be same sometime can't

Comment: In what units probability is? Looks like percents. In this case the total sum must be 100. Or you can suggest, that sum of this probabilities is 100%. Than you can generate random number from 0 to (10+20+10.50+19.99) and match interval which this number belongs to. [0,  10) - take c1, [10, 30) - take c2, [30, 40.50) - take c3, ...

Comment: Yes @PavelStepanets It is % and total will be 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) along with [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$rand = rand (0,(count($a)-1));

echo array_values($a)[$rand];
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/nTPaH AND https://3v4l.org/SSDRR

Note:- You can use [mt_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) instead of `rand()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` or `mt_rand()` generate a random number between given numbers,
For array there are some inbuilt function `array_rand()` and `shuffle()`

```
<?php
// array_rand
$input = array("Some", "Many", "More", "A Lot", "All");
$rand_key = array_rand($input);
echo $input[ $rand_key ] . "\n";
```

.

```
<?php
// shuffle
$input = array("Some", "Many", "More", "A Lot", "All");
shuffle($input);
echo $input[ 0 ];
```

You can read more here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Example:

array_rand - https://paiza.io/projects/e9Mo7QCkYqY37nvViWwG0A?language=php

shuffle - https://paiza.io/projects/xVs7O8-tu07JzNQQL0Gu4Q

May be you need this,